# Side garage door leak - voids in mortar - threshold problem?

Tags: doors, leak, brick, mortar, threshold

[image][image][image]I had an awful experience in having my home built a few years ago. I already had a window leak that ruined my floors in the living room after finding a cracked window seal that was “repaired” with silicone. I had all of that fixed, but during the process I noticed the row lock of brick under that window is not angled down at all, so it doesn’t shed water. I think I have the same problem with my garage door threshold. The row lock of brick under it isn’t angled down, but there are also voids in the mortar of the row lock of brick underneath. Water is coming into the garage under the threshold. I’ve lined it all with plastic and closed the door on it, and that has seemingly stopped the water from coming in under the threshold. I have some old mortar pieces that were chipped away from around the window when it was replaced. Can I crush up the mortar very finely and maybe add it to some silicone to fill the voids in the rowlock of brick under the door that’s leaking? I realize it’s probably a combination of the rowlock not being angled down to shed water plus the voids in the mortar beneath. Or - does it look like the threshold needs to be replaced too?

Comment: How long ago was the house built?  Builders usually have 5 years to repair defects, before it becomes your problem to fix.  A picture of the outside where the problem is, will help more than seeing water coming in.  Thanks for the second picture.

Comment: The builder is out of business now, and rightfully so, after all the people I’ve met that used him. He left a trail of devastated homeowners in my area.

Comment: I can also see a long sloppy line of clear caulk or silicone under the threshold on the inside, so they probably knew it was leaking. I’ve been putting out fires all over the house so to speak since it was built 3 years ago. I just now caught this. I honestly thought each time it was wet, it was from me tracking in water and grass from the yard. But this time it’s rained and I haven’t been out that door, so it is definitely leaking.

Comment: I’ve also contacted the brick company where my brick and mortar came from. They only sell huge bags of mortar which are over $100 each, so I don’t want to buy a whole bag, but would love to be able to use the mortar pieces from the window replacement that I saved if I could. I haven’t found any mortar repair type stuff at lowes or Home Depot that would match my light mortar.

Comment: A local brick layer probably deals with the same company, and will probably sell you the small amount needed if they have open bags/containers.